# Can I connect grounds of two different 9V batteries?

Tags: switches, ground, switching, toggle-switch

I want to make a backup battery connector for my project so I can power it externally if the internal battery dies.

For this, I'm planning to use a SPDT switch with the pole connected to the circuit's power input and the throws connecter to both the batteries positive terminals. In this way, the grounds of both the circuits will be connected to the circuit's gnd input all the time.

Is this okay? When I'm powering it from battery one, battery two's ground will also be connected to the circuit's gnd. Won't current flow from one battery to another?

Should I use a DPDT switch to switch both positive and negative wires?

Thanks a ton.

Comment: Will the switch have a “dead” time when changing from one to the other? Will this kill the device? Did you get a “make before break” switch?

Answer (score 1):

That sounds good, electricitly needs a circuit to flow, putting a switch in one wire is sufficient to stop the flow.

Answer (score 0):

Either SPDT or DPDT switch will work. As long as you break the loop connection between the batteries it's ok if one terminal is connected. Current only flows if you have two or more connections.